# Perpendicular distance question?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I've been having trouble with the following question:
"The point $P(x,y)$ is equidistant from the lines $2x+y-3=0$ and $x-2y+1=0$, which intersect at $A$. Use the distance formula to show that $|2x+y-3|=|x-2y+1|$."

Would you have to initially find the point of intersection, then use the formula? Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand; do you want to determine the locus of points $P(x,y)$ which are equidistant from the given lines?

Comment: The wording of the problem may be pretty confusing: if you denote $\;P=(a,b)\,$ instead of $\,(x,y)\,$ ,what the exercise asks *in fact* is to show that $$|2a+b-3|=|a-2b+1|$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

The distance from point $\;P=(a,b)\;$ to the line $\;Ax+By+C=0\;$ is given by

$$\frac{|Aa+Bb+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

It is a nice exercise, both in analytic geometry and/or in basic calculus, to prove the above indeed is the distance (i.e. the **minimal** distance) between the point and the line. Now solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The signed distance of $(x_0,y_0)$ from $ax+by+c=0$ is $\displaystyle {{ax_0+by_0+c}\over{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}$.

In your problem you have two lines with $(a_1,b_1,c_1)=(2,1,-3)$ and $(a_2,b_2,c_2)=(1,-2,1)$. The denominator expression becomes the same. So you get your equation without any further step.